# Редактирование шаблонов через статические файлы modx

Tags: modx

Можно ли редактировать шаблоны через файл, а не через админку и не только шаблоны

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, откройте страницу элемента(шаблон, сниппет, плагин, чанк) и в правой части вкладки внизу отметьте галочкой "Статичный", выберите путь,где будет хранится файл элемента и его "источник". И можно работать через IDE.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое